# Google Table chart not holding attributes when sorted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, google-api, google-visualization

following is my code where i am trying to add a new td which will simply show some color in form of legend like thing, i can successfully do this but when i click column header for sort the colors applied to the newly created TD are removed, here is my code

```
function drawVisualization2(dataArray,divName) {
                var colors_array = ['#3366cc','#dc3912','#ff9900','#109618','#990099'];
                var dataTbl = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
                var table1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'Table',
                    'containerId': 'chart3',
                    dataTable: dataTbl,
                    'options': {
                        'width': '500px'
                    }
                });
                table1.draw();
                function tableCleanUp() {
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(table1.getChart(), 'sort', tableCleanUp2);
                    tableCleanUp2(colors_array);
                }

                function tableCleanUp2(colors_array) {
                    var count = 0;
                    $('#chart3 tr').each(function () {
                        if(count > 0){
                            jQuery(this).append("<td class='google-visualization-table-td' style='background-color: "+colors_array[count-1]+";'></td>");
                        }
                        count ++;
                    });
                }
                google.visualization.events.addListener(table1, 'ready', tableCleanUp);
            }
```

for reference , i am following table chart as provided here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

my table structure is somewhat like this after i create a TD using jquery

```
<table class="google-visualization-table-table" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
       <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-head">
           <td class="google-visualization-table-th gradient google-visualization-table-sorthdr">
           <td class="google-visualization-table-th gradient google-visualization-table-sorthdr">
           <td class="google-visualization-table-th gradient google-visualization-table-sorthdr">
           <td class="google-visualization-table-th gradient google-visualization-table-sorthdr">
      </tr>
      <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
           <td class="google-visualization-table-td"> PSYCHOSES</td>
           <td class="google-visualization-table-td">644300589.00</td>
           <td class="google-visualization-table-td">1683487522.00</td>
           <td class="google-visualization-table-td">38.27</td>
           <td class="google-visualization-table-td" style="background-color: #3366cc;">  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
      <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
      <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-odd">
      <tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even">
</tbody>
</table>
```

After i Sort the column i get some thing like this with every TD (except header)

```
<td class="google-visualization-table-td" style="background-color: undefined;">
```

can some 1 tell me how keep the background-color after sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simpler way to get what you want without having to resort to adding an extra column after drawing: use a DataView to add in a calculated column:

```
var columns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataTbl.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columns.push(i);
}
columns.push({
    type: 'string',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        // set the background of an empty cell to the color of this row in the colors array
        return {v: '', p: {style: 'background-color: ' + colors_array[row]}};
    }
});

var table1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart3',
    dataTable: dataTbl,
    options: {
        width: 500, // use an integer here, not a string
        allowHtml: true
    },
    view: {
        columns: columns
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/89FzH/

Comment: thanks for a quick response, so i assume you dont want me to create new TD instead push column in the table, i havnet tried your code yet, but what i want to know is that i am putting different colors in every new created TD are you doing same functionality?

Comment: Yes, this maps colors in your `colors` array to specific rows in the DataTable, so the colors will stay with the row when it is sorted.

Comment: ok tried your code but i am unable to populate any background-color in the newly created Column, also there is no error in the code, In short  column is created but no color in that column

Comment: I think we need some modification here `calc: function (dt, row) {
        // set the background of an empty cell to the color of this row in the colors array
        return {v: '', p: {style: 'background-color: ' + colors[row]}};
    }`, I am getting is the above selector i alerted and i can get there but some how color change is not triggered

Comment: I had a couple of typos in the code, and you need to set the `allowHtml` option to `true` as well.  I updated my answer.  Here's a jsfiddle example too: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/89FzH/

Comment: i corrected Typos in my code and now trying `allowHtml` option